# Getting cronjob to work in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, cron, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to create a cronjob, I've followed multiple tutorials and searched Stackoverflow but I think I am making a misstake because it doesn't work.

Under Ubuntu 14 this is in my users account Cronjob file

```
* 16 * * * cd work/homefolder/homefolder && scrapy crawl scrape1
```

with the use of:

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

I can see the cron job is run but it doesn't execute the command. I also
can not see what is going wrong.

Just typing it in the terminal does work

```
cd
cd work/homefolder/homefolder && scrapy crawl scrape1
```

The whole path to the folder is

```
/home/NAMEOFUSER/work/homefolder/homefolder
```

Does anybody know why it doesn't work or where I can find what is going wrong?

Thank you

Comment: See the [crontab tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) for debugging tips and common problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the absolute path, not the relative path in the cronjob file.

Try `* 16 * * * cd /home/NAMEOFUSER/work/homefolder/homefolder && scrapy crawl scrape1`

But I'd rather have a script ready that does the work for you (including changing directories) and call that directly:

`* 16 * * * /home/NAMEOFUSER/work/homefolder/homefolder/scrape.sh`

The contents of the `scrape.sh` can look like this:

```
!#/bin/sh
cd /home/NAMEOFUSER/work/homefolder/homefolder && scrapy crawl scrape1
```

Make sure to update your permissions, so that the cron demon has access.

Furthermore, the preferred way of editing cronjobs on Ubuntu is running `crontab -e`

Comment: Thank you, I tried executing a python script by using your method and it works. 

Only "scrapy crawl scrape1" command still doesn't work so it probably crashes or something, how can I found what is going on with it ?

Thanks for helping out again!

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the scrape.sh. Make sure you update your reading and execution permissions, so the cronjob can be successfully executed.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it by adding 'PATH=/usr/local/bin' so it could locate Scrapy